# Restricting maps between strict henselisations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory

$\require{AMScd}$I am currently thinking about [(strict) henselisations](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BSK) but I don't know too much literature about the topic. So I am wondering if there is a natural way to restrict maps between strict henselisations to henselisations:

Let $A$, $B$ be local rings with an injective homomorphism $h:A\to B$. If I have a homomorphism $f:A^\text{sh} \to B^\text{sh}$, is there always a homomorphism $g:A^\text h \to B^\text h$ such that the following diagram commutes?

\begin{CD}
A^\text{sh} @>f>> B^\text{sh}\\
@AAA @AAA\\
A^\text h @>>g> B^\text h
\end{CD}

Equivalently, I am asking if you start with $x \in A^\text h \subset A^\text{sh}$, is $f(x) \in B^\text h$? It feels like this should be related to Galois theory, where Galois extensions fix the base field.

(Note: There might be requirements on $A$ and $B$ like being normal, or $B$ being a field. I'm also interested in answers with more assumptions than stated above.)

**Clarifications:**
The underlying injective homomorphism $h: A \to B$ is *not necessarily a local map* but $f$ commutes with $h$.

\begin{CD}
A^\text{sh} @>f>> B^\text{sh}\\
@AAA @AAA\\
A @>>h> B
\end{CD}

The example I have in mind is the following: Pick a ring $R$ and a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \in R$ and a map $\operatorname{Frac}(R) \to \operatorname{Frac}(R)^\text{sep}$ (i.e. a geometric point over the generic point of my curve $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$). Then $A := R_{\mathfrak{m}}$, $B:=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$, the map $h: A \to B$ is not local and $B \to B^\text{sh} = \operatorname{Frac}(R) ^\text{sep}$ is given by above chosen geometric point.

Comment: Is the homomorphism $f$ supposed to form a similar commutative diagram with the injective homomorphism $A \to B$?

Comment: @WillSawin updated the post above. It does commute with the injective homomorphism $A \to B$ but that one is not local, which seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $A= k[x]_{(x)}$, the localization of the ring of polynomials in one variable at the maximal ideal $(x)$, and $B = k(x)$.

Assume (for simplicity) that the characteristic of $k$ is not $2$.

Then there exists $y \in A^h$ satisfying $y^2 = 1+x$, as that polynomial splits into distinct linear factors modulo $x$.

But there exists no $y \in B^h = B$ satisfying that equation, as writing $y = f/g$ we would have $f^2 = g^2(1+x)$ so $$2 \deg f = \deg f^2= \deg (g^2 (1+x)) = 2\deg g+1$$

So there can be no homomorphism $A^h \to B^h$ sending $x$ to $x$ (as it must to form a commutative diagram with the induced map on strict henselizations).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** This answer is not suitable as the OP does not assume that the map $A\to B$ is local. See clarification by the OP and counter example by Sawin. Sorry.

This is true, without restrictions, and in a slightly more general formulation: star with a local homomorphism $f:A\to B$ and give yourself a morphism $\Omega\to \Omega'$, where $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ are the residue fields of the strict henselisations of $A$ and $B$ respectively, such that $A\to A^{sh}\to \Omega\to\Omega'$ coincide with $A\to B\to B^{sh}\to \Omega'$. Then, there are unique $f^h:A^h\to B^h$ and $f^{sh}: A^{sh}\to B^{sh}$ making your diagram with $f^h$ (resp. $f^{sh}$) commute. Thus there is such a $g$ and it must be $f^h$.

Reference: [Raynaud, *Anneaux locaux henseliens*, VIII, 3, Proposition 4].

Comment: The question doesn't actually say, though it certainly seems to imply, that $f^\text{sh}$ comes from the map $A \to B$ (hence @WillSawin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408644/restricting-maps-between-strict-henselisations#comment1048238_408644)).

Comment: Ohh. I see. I overlooked that indeed. I will leave it as it is for now, in case the  OP meant what I assumed.

Comment: Thank you. I added a clarification above. I think the issue I am experiencing is that the underlying map is not a local map, but all the results I encounter always assume it is.